# Route URL not Properly Working for an Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have added a second area as shown below;

```
public class MerchantAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Merchant";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Merchant_default",
            "Merchant/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Merchant", id = "" },
            new[] { "Dplus.Merchant.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

When i type the url in as **http://localhost:7190/merchant/home**. Everything works great but when i type **http://localhost:7190/merchant** (without controller name) then i get the following error;

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>       The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I have similar area called **"Admin"** and the exact code works for it. But for this second area it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a folder in the root named `merchant`, I suspect you do because it's trying to list the contents of it.

Comment: You have a directory in your folder called Merchant.  MVC will pass this through and try to list the contents.

Comment: yes i have, because i have used custom view engines.

Comment: the problem was that directory name, i have to change it to something else. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

As per comment by @Erik, My **Area name and directory name is the same**. Basically i am using a custom view engine. So what i did is change the directory name to something other than the MVC Area name e.g AdministrationMerchant 
Now browsing the same URL works!